# Sum and Divide a Bigint, Results with decimal precision?

Tags: t-sql

I am storing a `bigint` value (for file sizes) in a table.  I need to group on one column and for the `filesizes` (which are in bytes).  I would like to have a column showing them by GB.  This would mean `Sum(FileSize/1024/1024/1024)` which is not showing any decimal places.  My research seems to indicate this may be due to truncation rather than rounding.

I have tried many options of `cast` and `convert`, but cannot seem to find any information about how to `sum` and `divide` a `bigint`, and maintain the decimals.  If I take the sum and divide it in Excel, I get the decimals, which tells me there has to be a way to do this in SQL.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Sum(CAST(FileSize AS FLOAT)/1024/1024/1024)
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found that this would work: case when cast(sum(d.filesize)/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0 as decimal(10,5))is null
then '0' else cast(sum(d.filesize)/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0 as decimal(10,5)) 
end as SessionSizeGB     I will try yours to see the difference.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I don't know how.  I am so new to this site.  I clicked the checkmark.  Is there something else?